# symbolic link to a text file in command line

Tags: windows, cmd, symlink

Im trying to create a symbolic link to a text file with directory:

> C:\users\me\textfile.txt

where the shortcut is in the same folder (for simplicity)

using command:

```
mklink /d "C:\users\me\textfileshortcut.lnk" "C:\users\me\textfile.txt"
```

but this just creates a folder with the name `textfileshortcut.lnk` and not a shortcut to a file.

**What am i doing wrong?**

I dont have too much experience with command line but i need it for this one task.

Comment: Note for this purpose i only need to create a regular windows shortcut to a file which can be read programmatically as if it was the file itself so a symbolic link is not essential. It does however have to be done via command line.

Comment: according to `mklink /?` `/d` creates a link to a folder, not a file.

Answer (score 0):

Create the symlink for a file using the below cmd command.

```
mklink "C:\users\me\textfileshortcut.lnk" "C:\users\me\textfile.txt"
```

`/d` or `/D` will create the directory symlink.